# Why are the running states stored in high order bits in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java

```
    private static final int COUNT_BITS = Integer.SIZE - 3;    
// runState is stored in the high-order bits
private static final int RUNNING    = -1 << COUNT_BITS;
private static final int SHUTDOWN   =  0 << COUNT_BITS;
```

as above.Why are the running states stored in high order bits in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look a bit around this code [in the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#378):

```
private static final int COUNT_BITS = Integer.SIZE - 3;
private static final int CAPACITY   = (1 << COUNT_BITS) - 1;

// runState is stored in the high-order bits
private static final int RUNNING    = -1 << COUNT_BITS;
private static final int SHUTDOWN   =  0 << COUNT_BITS;
private static final int STOP       =  1 << COUNT_BITS;
private static final int TIDYING    =  2 << COUNT_BITS;
private static final int TERMINATED =  3 << COUNT_BITS;

// Packing and unpacking ctl
private static int runStateOf(int c)     { return c & ~CAPACITY; }
private static int workerCountOf(int c)  { return c & CAPACITY; }
private static int ctlOf(int rs, int wc) { return rs | wc; }
```

Run state is stored in the high-order bits; worker count is stored in the low-order bits. Packing the two into a single `int` just saves a bit of memory.